# Node JS App Breaking When Deployed to Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku

I've recently deployed my Node JS ecommerce app to Heroku. The app works fine in development, but I'm getting an application error in production when I visit /cart. I think I've managed to narrow the issue down to my use of cookies - my createCart function does not seem to be creating the necessary cookie to store the cart token. Does anyone know what's causing this/how to fix it? Thanks!

`heroku logs` shows me this error: `Error: Unhandled "error" event. (null)`

cart.js:

```
module.exports = function(app){

// Dependencies and imported functions
const cookie = require('cookie');
const path = require('path');
const appDir = path.dirname(require.main.filename);
const cartMod = require("../modules/cart");
const cartCount = cartMod.itemCount;
const crypto = require("crypto");

// DB
const Cart = require('../models/carts');
const CartItem = require('../models/cart_items');
const Discount = require('../models/discounts');
const Product = require('../models/products');

const createCart = (req, res, next) => {
  var token = crypto.randomBytes(20).toString("hex");
  Cart.create({token: token, discount: null}, function(err, cart) {
    if (err || !cart) throw err;
    console.log(token);
    res.setHeader('Set-Cookie', cookie.serialize("cart_token", token, {
      path: "/",
      maxAge: 60 * 60 * 24 * 7 // 1 week
    }));
    return next();
  });
};

const checkCart = (req, res, next) => {
  var token = req.cookies["cart_token"];
  if (!token) {
    createCart(res, res, next);
  } else {
    Cart.find({token: token}, function(err, cart) {
      if (err || !cart) createCart(res, res, next);
      return next();
    });
  }
};

const cartIndex = (req, res, cartCount) => {
  var token = req.cookies["cart_token"];
  console.log(token)
  Cart.findOne({token: token}, function(err, cart) {
    if (err || !cart) throw err;
    if (cart.discount) {
      Discount.findById(cart.discount, function(err, discount) {
        if (err || !discount) throw err;
        console.log(discount)
        displayCartItems(res, cart._id, discount.percent, cartCount);
      });
    } else {
      displayCartItems(res, cart._id, 0, cartCount);
    }
  });
};

app.get('/cart', checkCart, function (req, res, next) {
  cartCount(req, res, cartIndex);
});

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
app.set('trust proxy', 1)
```

Adding this to my app.js fixed the problem.